# how can i change int64 to Datetime in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

i use for change int64 datatype to Date time type with 'to_datetime'method but the result is too weird.

```
df['DEATH_YMD'] = pd.to_datetime(df["DEATH_YMD"], unit='s')
```

the result is it.

> PT_SBST_NO
> P00001   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020160515
> P00002   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020091001
> P00003   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020081031
> P00004   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020141105
> P00005   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020110324
> Name: DEATH_YMD, dtype: datetime64[ns]

but i wanna make new columns like below

20160515
20091001

how do i for it?

```
original data

df['DEATH_YMD'].value_counts()

20130704    18
20130711    18
20130703    18
20130708    18
20130709    18
            ..
20140513     1
20161115     1
20081022     1
20081014     1
20160516     1
Name: DEATH_YMD, Length: 1811, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you show the original data ?

Comment: how do i update in stack overflow? I'm not good at using this :(

Comment: you can Click edit

Comment: it is right for original data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a format:

```
df['DEATH_YMD'] = pd.to_datetime(df["DEATH_YMD"], format='%Y%m%d')
```

The `unit` param is used when the number is a timestamp.